# Max value of count in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these tables, Orders Table:

```
Name       Null?    Type  
ORDER_ID  NOT NULL  NUMBER(5)  
CUSTOMER_ID         NUMBER(8)  
SHIPMENT_METHOD_ID  NUMBER(2)
```

and Shipment_method Table:

```
Name               Null?      Type  
SHIPMENT_METHOD_ID  NOT NULL  NUMBER(2)  
SHIPMENT_DESCRIPTION          VARCHAR2(80)
```

I'm trying to get the most used shipping method based on the orders, and I'm kind of a beginner here so I need some help.
I'm thinking if it's possible to have MAX(count(order_id)) but how can I do that for each shipment_method_id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another approach:

```
select shipment_method_id, shipment_description, count(*) as num_orders
  from orders
  join shipment_method
 using (shipment_method_id)
 group by shipment_method_id, shipment_description
having count(*) = (select max(count(order_id))
                     from orders
                    group by shipment_method_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need MAX, you just need to return the top row

```
SELECT Shipment_Method_Desc
FROM (
    SELECT Shipment_Method_ID, Shipment_Method_Desc, COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM Shipment_Method s
    JOIN Orders o ON s.Shipment_Method_ID = o.Shipment_Method_ID
    GROUP BY Shipment_Method_ID
    ORDER BY ct DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

If you're using Oracle 12c or newer, you can use the [row limiting clause](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php) instead of the subquery:

```
SELECT Shipment_Method_ID, Shipment_Method_Desc, COUNT(*) AS ct
FROM Shipment_Method s
JOIN Orders o ON s.Shipment_Method_ID = o.Shipment_Method_ID
GROUP BY Shipment_Method_ID
ORDER BY ct DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that allows for more than one Shipment Method having the same maximum number of Orders.

```
SELECT shipment_method_id
      ,shipment_description
      ,orders
FROM
   (SELECT shipment_method_id
          ,shipment_description
          ,orders
          ,rank() OVER (ORDER BY orders DESC) orders_rank
    FROM
       (SELECT smm.shipment_method_id
              ,smm.shipment_description
              ,count(*) orders
        FROM orders odr
             INNER JOIN shipment_method smm
               ON (smm.shipment_method_id = odr.shipment_method_id)
        GROUP BY smm.shipment_method_id
                ,smm.shipment_description
       )
   )
WHERE orders_rank = 1
```

Comment: This uses inline views to be more efficient, the inner select gets count of orders by shipment method, for this ranks these according to the count, and then picks the record(s) with the top rank. Barmar's answer does not cater for multiple shipment methods with the same number of orders. Brian DeMilia's answer will require two full table scans on Orders (one in the main query and one to get the maximum in the `HAVING` clause) so may make take longer to execute. My answer users analytic functions to avoid this double scan of Orders.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, you may find using `with` useful which allows to have kind of named intermediate results:

```
with STATS as (select SHIPMENT_METHOD_ID, count(*) as N 
               from ORDERS group by SHIPMENT_METHOD_ID)
, MAXIMUM as (select max(N) as N from STATS)
select SHIPMENT_METHOD_ID, SHIPMENT_DESCRIPTION 
from STATS
join MAXIMUM on STATS.N = MAXIMUM.N
natural join SHIPMENT_METHOD
```